# CORS on Custom Keycloak Endpoints

Tags: cors, keycloak

I have created a custom Keycloak endpoint (using a custom realm resource provider factory).  I'm able to post to this endpoint using Postman and it works as expected.  When I attempt to post to it from my SPA (Angular) app, I get a CORS error.

My web origins are configured correctly in my Keycloak client configuration.  But these appear to not apply to my custom endpoint.

How do I configure my endpoint to allow cross origin POSTs?

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the suggested question.  This question deals specifically with custom endpoints.

Comment: @sideshowbarker please do not mark questions as duplicate before taking the time to fully understand the question and how it differs from the linked questions.

Comment: Reopened. But the question *“How do I configure my endpoint to allow cross origin POSTs?”* is too broad. And you say, *“My web origins are configured correctly in my Keycloak client configuration”* but you don’t show any code for your configuration nor for your frontend code. You say, *“I get a CORS error”* but you don’t show the actual error message. To get help from others here, you want to show what you’ve tried so far, and cite any specific errors you’ve run into. (And by the way, downvote not from me.)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to configure my custom endpoint to support CORS by doing the following:

Added a preflight jax-rs endpoint method.  This allows the browser to make the preflight OPTIONS request and receive information about what headers, methods, origins, etc are allowed:

```
@OPTIONS
@Path("users")
public Response handleCorsPreflight(@Context final HttpRequest request) {
    logger.info("Received CORS preflight request for ext/user; request is " + request);
    return Cors.add(request, Response.ok())
            .preflight()
            .allowAllOrigins()
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE")
            .exposedHeaders("Location")
            .auth()
            .build();
}
```

It's unclear to me whether there is a global way of doing this.  It seems like there should be.

In my actual endpoint methods, I had to process the response with Keycloak's static `Cors.add` method.  For example:

```
@POST
@Path("foo")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createFoo(final FooRepresentation rep,
                                                   @Context final HttpRequest request,
                                                   @Context final HttpHeaders headers) {
Response response = createFoo(rep);
return Cors.add(request, Response.fromResponse(response))
            .allowAllOrigins()
            .allowedMethods("GET", "PUT", "POST", "DELETE")
            .exposedHeaders("Location")
            .auth()
            .build();

}
```

The response here allows all origins.  I don't recommend this, but it got this code working.  It's probably possible to tie into Keycloak's client settings and return the value set in "web origin".  I haven't investigated this yet.